# Querying hyperledger-composer REST services via Node-RED

Tags: node-red, hyperledger-composer

I have deployed a sample network of car auction in hyperledger composer and then created 1 Hyperledger-composer-node out and provided my connection configurations in it. Also created 1 inject node in which json is mentioned. But even after deploying, I am not able to see the changes in my composer rest server.

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of composer do you have?, and when you installed the node red nodes did you install `node-red-contrib-composer`?

Comment: I am using composer of version 0.13.1. And yes, I have installed node-red-contrib-composer

Comment: That is quite an old version of composer i would try updating to the latest, and make sure you also have the latest version of the node red nodes. There have been quite alot of changes which might mean that there is incompatibility between the version of composer you have and the version of the node red nodes you have

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of Hyperledger Composer. Would suggest to update to the latest, and make sure you also have the latest version of the Node Red nodes.

There have been quite a lot of changes which might mean that there is incompatibility between the version of Composer you have currently and the version of the Node Red nodes you have.